# Stop eclipse renaming inside strings

Tags: eclipse, string, replace, refactoring, rename

I've been having this problem for some time and have never bothered to fix it since Eclipse has a horrible help system and I can't seem to find the right Google keywords to find what I need.

My problem is that when I refactor a class name, eclipse looks for all potential locations of that name and replaces them.

For instance, if I have a string inside a test case for the "list command" that says something like, "List - list all the users on a team", when I refactor the List.java class to something like UserListCommand.java, the expression inside the string also changes to "UserListCommand - list all the users on a team"

This is SOOO annoying! And like I said, Google is useless when you cannot even think of the right keywords to use.

Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen it do this.  Are you using the Rename Refactor, or are you simply doing Find & Replace?

Comment: I only notice it when I do a refactor by renaming. I hardly ever use find and replace and especially not for a class name... I'm confused now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse calls this updating textual occurrences in comments and strings.   I sometimes turn this on  so javadoc gets updated correctly if I didn't properly link it.  But it can be a pain because it sometimes replaces substrings that match.

I've only seen this when renaming classes or interfaces (methods don't seem to do this, at least not for me),

You need to open the Rename Dialog to stop eclipse from updating textual occurrences in comments and strings:

Highlight the type you want to rename, then either:

1. press Shift+Alt+R
2. Right click, then go to refactor->rename.. then instead of typing the new name, there should now be a yellow context popup menu under the class name to be changed which says "Enter new name, press **Enter** to refactor", notice that there is a down arrow to expand the menu.  If you press that instead of enter a new name a new drop down menu appears, select Open Rename Dialog...

Once the Rename Dialog is open:

uncheck "update textual occurences in comments and strings (forces preview)" and "Update fully qualified names in non-Java text files (forces preview)"

Hope that helps

Comment: it is really useful, but must be used sparingly and with caution, I was in a hurry and changed a variable named "value" and got about 20 classes comments and strings messed, 2 days later I discovered it, took me 1h to fix hehe :)