# Eclipse refactoring does renaming outside the current project?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-luna

I use Eclipse Luna and do refactoring to rename a class name in my project A. But the refactoring does rename also JSP files in other prjects that contain this classname? Is this a configuration type of thing?

Comment: Are you saying Eclipse is actually *renaming* JSP files, or just updating their contents with the new name of the class?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Eclipse is updating their contents with the new name of a referenced class. But I am upset that it occurs in other projects than the one I am working in!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a problem if eclipse *didnt'* update the referenced class in related projects since it would cause compiler errors.

If your problem is eclipse is renaming the same String name as your class in other text files, then look at this other stackoverflow answer:
[Stop eclipse renaming inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176609/stop-eclipse-renaming-inside-strings)

Comment: Related project is every project that happens to be open within Eclipse?

Comment: yes, it is probably better to say *referenced* project